# Как реализовать с помощью UserControl рисование графика?

Tags: c#

У меня в задании написано: "Рисование графика функции вынеси в отдельный User Control - должен получиться пользовательский элемент управления, который рисует график функции."

Для рисования графиков использую PictureBox. Но при создании UserControl в Toolbox элемент PictureBox отсутствует.

Как же быть?

После добавления PictureBox я описываю обработчик для рисования графика для этого PictureBox. Как я понимаю также надо добавить конструктор чтобы передавать параметры для рисования графика. Что еще нужно сделать?                                               
И где можно прочитать на примере как создавать и использовать UserControl?

Comment: вот смотрю на ваши вопросы и думается что вы не с той стороны начали программирование учить...

Comment: подскажите с какой стороны надо учить

Comment: взять какой-нибудь учебник и начинать с простых вещей, с самих основ языка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаёте UserControl.

Дизайнер не трогаете.

Создаёте у Вашего UserControl метод / свойство, отвечающее за данные, по которым строится график. Этот метод / свойство должно обновить данные внутри UserControl и вызвать Invalidate().

Перекрываете OnPaint и в обработчике события рисуете график брашами на основе данных, заданных в предыдущем члене класса.

Answer (score 1):

В контекстном меню панели выбора компонентов есть пункт "Choose Items...", который показывает окошко, настраивающее список компонент, кои будут там.

Вот, наглядно:

[image: сие окошко]

Там тыкните галочку нужную, всё и появится.

**UPD**:

Да самодельные контролы используются абсолютно так же, как и стандартные. Задайте свойства, методы контрола. Самые важные из них, и правда, можно настраивать и в конструкторе.

Для графика что надо? Настройка осей, сетки, цветов различных. Ну и операции с данными хотя бы - добавить линию (из набора точек и стиля), изменить, удалить.

Для начала попробуйте сделать простейший контрол, для получения представления. А там уже и до графика недалеко.

Comment: У меня уже была установлена эта галочка, но PictureBox, все равно не появилась. Также у вас UserControl1.cs, а у меня UserControl1.xaml.cs и UserControl1.xaml Может я не то открыл?

Comment: все, разобрался, нашел

Comment: мне бы только надо понять как создать пользовательский элемент  управления с PictureBox и как туда передать массивы, а как с помощью PictureBox нарисовать необходимые мне кривые я знаю

Answer (score 0):

[Вот](http://books.ifmo.ru/book/pdf/673.pdf) очень хрошее пособие, включающее рисование на userform. Без picturebox. Все намного удобнее - canvas и браши

Comment: но там не используется User Control, а мне нужно использовать User Control

Comment: Да разницы где рисовать - принцип-то один и тот же=)

Comment: Как нарисовать я знаю, но как использовать для этой цели и вообще как использовать UserControl я не представляю, а это я и хочу узнать